# How to do Button_Click from keybord?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to do my "Button_click" when I press some key on keyboard?                           
 My code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + b.Text;        
}

private void button1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    Char ch0 = '0';
    if (e.KeyChar == ch0)
    {
        //MyButtonClick event
    }
}
```

...

KeyPress event runs only when the button on form in focus, but I need to KeyPress worked just as I push the button on my keyboard.
 Please, give an exaple in you'r answer.

 And don't be strict, I am only a beginner...

Answer (score 2):

It is not completely clear that what are you asking, but I guess you want to do the same action on both keypress of your keyboard and when user clicks on the button.

look at [this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN for key_press:

```
void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Form.KeyPress: '" +
            e.KeyChar.ToString() + "' pressed.");

        switch (e.KeyChar)
        {
            case (char)49:
            case (char)52:
            case (char)55:
                MessageBox.Show("Form.KeyPress: '" +
                    e.KeyChar.ToString() + "' consumed.");
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

To do the same action in 2 event, you can write another method and call them from both events.

```
public void MyAction(mypars)
{
....
}

void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  MyAction(mypars);
}
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyAction(mypars);
}
```

It is also possible to call another event method, since they are like other methods, but I really do not suggest that! but it is like this:

```
private void button1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  Button_Click(sender,new EventArgs());
}
```

---

### Update

You have to be better than "I want my button to be pressed". If you mean the visuals, you can set the focus of the control, like:

```
myButton.Focus();
```

Hope I could help you out :)

### update 2

you have to use it like this

```
void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  MyAction(mypars);
  myButton.Focus();
}
```

if you need it to focus only on special chars, then check it before doing anythig like

```
void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57)
  {
    MyAction(mypars);
    myButton.Focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not what I want, I want, when I click on my keyboard button on the form button will be pressed (without press the button on form before)